# MySQL replication - Slave is connecting to master but not replicating

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, database-replication, master-slave

I am setting up a master slave replication in my two digitalocean droplets by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) post from digitalocean. 

After following all the steps I'm still getting this sql error when running
**show slave status\G**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: master_private_IP
              Master_User: slave_user
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1272
           Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
            Relay_Log_Pos: 320
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: No
          Replicate_Do_DB:
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 1133
               Last_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user 
   table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 
   TO 'slave_user'@'%''
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 595
          Relay_Log_Space: 1577
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
    Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error:
           Last_SQL_Errno: 1133
           Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user 
    table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 
    *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%''
    Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
         Master_Server_Id: 1
              Master_UUID: 77e2487f-7234-11e8-bf1c-32d9b5470a6f
         Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                SQL_Delay: 0
      SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
  Slave_SQL_Running_State:
       Master_Retry_Count: 86400
              Master_Bind:
  Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
 Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 180619 05:35:21
           Master_SSL_Crl:
       Master_SSL_Crlpath:
       Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
        Executed_Gtid_Set:
            Auto_Position: 0
     Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
             Channel_Name:
       Master_TLS_Version:
```

Please help me find a solution. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `binlog_do_db = newdatabase` is terrible advice.  That makes no sense at all.  You should probably find a different tutorial.

Comment: i have changed the `binlog_do_db` to `replicate_do_db`.

Comment: I just skipped the sql error using this query

`SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;`

and it solved the problem,but i came to know this is not an efficient way,
Please suggest me a stable way for achieving master slave replication.

Comment: That does not solve the problem, it simply ignores the error and continues... so it is not safe unless you understand the reason for the error and have taken the necessary steps to ensure consistency.  Do not attempt selective replication -- replicate the entire server.  Selective replication is an extremely complex topic and without the necessary expertise to ensure proper setup, your replica will eventually fail or silently diverge from the master.

Comment: `Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user 
    table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 
    *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%''`

here the default database parameter is empty,is this the thing causing the error?, am i missing something? 
**PS**: I'm a beginner